# Am I interpreting this notation correctly?

Tags: notation, index-notation, clustering

I'm trying to parse [a paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.06856.pdf) about a new (to me) clustering algorithm into code, and I want to make sure I understand the math correctly... but the notation is holding me up. From page 3 , equation 2:

$$
L(\mathcal{M};x) = \sum_{j=1}^n \min_{m \in \mathcal{M}\cup\{x\}} d(m, x_j)
$$

My interpretation of this is "The cost of assigning point $x$ to set $\mathcal{M}$ equals the sum of distances between $m$ and $x_j$ where $m$ is the closest object to $x_j$.

However, I'm afraid that my interpretation of this is muddied because I know that's how other, similar algorithms work. This might seem trivial, so I hope you will forgive me: Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: I have a masters in ML. Without having looked at the paper, this interpretation seems correct to me. However, you need to add an additional detail: $m$ is the closest object to $x_j$ out of $M \cup \{x\}$.

Comment: @CrabMan Hey, thanks. Yes, as we are considering $x$ as a candidate for insertion into $\mathcal{M}$, that makes sense. I have a master's degree in math, but I still suck at it, so thanks for your help ;)